# Ubuntu 16.04 not mounting windows partitions

Tags: 16.04

I have a problem with Ubuntu mounting windows partitions. When I turn on the computer, Ubuntu is not mounting my windows partition (sda3).
It gives this error message:

Unable to access "Main memory"
[error shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFTae.pngfile:///home/shavkatjon/Pictures/Screenshot%20from%202016-10-20%2013-30-00.png)

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, simply mount the NTFS partition as read-only. Rather than typing out all the steps, [here](http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/10/make-ntfs-partitions-read-only-in-ubuntu/) is a tutorial to do what you want.

Alternatively you can go into windows and disable fast startup, [this](http://lifehacker.com/enable-this-setting-to-make-windows-10-boot-up-faster-1743697169) guide shows how to enable it, which is the opposite of what you're trying to do, however disabling fast startup just requires un-checking the box.Beware that by un-checking this windows will take longer to start, and this procedure is only applicable to windows 8, 8.1 and 10.

Comment: @ShavkatjonMamashokirov If this helped you, please mark this as the correct answer so others can find the answer easily.

Comment: [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/145904/301745) already has the directions for mounting the NTFS as read-only and for disabling Fast Startup.

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and type

```
 sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdXY
```

XY: label...eg sda3
`Still You can't access one of the windows disc(one which windows is installed in)`

For permanent solution: turn off hibernation(in windows)

Open command prompt as administrator and type

```
 powercfg -h off
```

If problem occurs again after next bootup

Open run prompt from start menu

```
 1. Type and Start msconfig.exe 
 2. On the general tab select "Selective startup" and uncheck "Load startup items".
 3. On the services tab unselect all first
 4. Runt the command "powercfg -h off" to turn off hibernation.
 5. Reboot
 6. If hibernation is still deactivated start msconfig.exe again and activate half of the services.
 7. Repeat 5 and 6 until you find the service causing hibernation to be turned back on       (don't forget to do step 4 if it is activated again).
```